# PHP $_POST empty - just displays "Array ( )"

Tags: php, post

Probably a very basic PHP question but can anyone offer any clues as to why my $_POST value on the following is empty so my code never runs. When I print it out it just displays "Array ( )"
I'm fairly certain this same code worked on my old server but after migrating the site to a new host (linux) it's not working. And I did have problems with the new host insisting on all fieldnames being case sensitive (if this offers any clues). Just for info this isn't the full code, just an excerpt. Many thanks in advance.

```
//add-album.php...

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="POST">
    <span class="admin-title">Upload a new album</span> 
    <input name="album-name"  type="text" value="" size="30"  maxlength="100"/>  
    <input name="album_submit" type="submit" value ="ADD ALBUM" />
</form> 

//index.php...

echo 'this text is displaying';
print_r($_POST);
if(isset($_POST['album_submit'])) 
    {
    do something...
```

Comment: What do you get with echo $_POST['album_submit']; It should say ADD ALBUM.

Comment: Copy-pasted the code. Works for me.

Comment: Try printing `phpinfo();` (only this line) on index.php an browse the file. Then check the value for the `enable_post_data_reading` directive. It should be On, but just in case...

Comment: This could be due to some server redirection, your POST is lost along the way.

Comment: echoing $_POST['album_submit'] displays nothing at all !

Comment: enable_post_data_reading = On

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all your help. It was the .htaccess file redirect causing the problem (code below)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

Now I just need to work out how to remove the php suffix without screwing everything else up!